# Most efficient way to merge to two sorted Java Linked List (Not custom Linked List)

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

if a method is merging two sorted Lists, and signature looks like below, someone can pass in a Linked List, and if you use a.get(index), the total runtime complexity will be O(N^2). So seems like Iterators are the only way to go to get O(N) runtime. But it makes the code a bit clunky. Is there any way to simplify this code while maintaining O(N) runtime? Thanks for your help!

```
 public static List<Integer> mergeListEfficient(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> firstItr = a.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> secondItr = b.iterator();
    Integer firstVal = firstItr.hasNext() ? firstItr.next() : null;
    Integer secondVal = secondItr.hasNext() ? secondItr.next() : null;

    while (firstVal != null || secondVal != null) {
        if (firstVal != null && secondVal != null) {
            if (firstVal < secondVal) {
                result.add(firstVal);
                firstVal = firstItr.hasNext() ? firstItr.next() : null;
            } else {
                result.add(secondVal);
                secondVal = secondItr.hasNext() ? secondItr.next() : null;
            }
        } else if (firstVal != null) {
            result.add(firstVal);
            firstVal = firstItr.hasNext() ? firstItr.next() : null;
        } else {
            result.add(secondVal);
            secondVal = secondItr.hasNext() ? secondItr.next() : null;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> a = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(5);

    List<Integer> b = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
    b.add(3);
    b.add(5);
    b.add(6);

    System.out.println(mergeListEfficient(a, b));
    //prints correctly [2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
}
```

Comment: `return Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Hi there, this is an interview question, so I don't think you can use the Stream framework. Think of this like, merge two sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to introduce new class with interface that better suite for this task.

```
public class App {
    public static List<Integer> mergeListEfficient(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        BetterIterator firstItr = new BetterIterator(a.iterator());
        BetterIterator secondItr = new BetterIterator(b.iterator());

        while (firstItr.hasValue() && secondItr.hasValue()) {
            Integer firstVal = firstItr.getValue();
            Integer secondVal = secondItr.getValue();
            if (firstVal < secondVal) {
                result.add(firstVal);
                firstItr.move();
            } else {
                result.add(secondVal);
                secondItr.move();
            }
        }
        for(;firstItr.hasValue();firstItr.move()){
            result.add(firstItr.getValue());
        }
        for(;secondItr.hasValue();secondItr.move()){
            result.add(secondItr.getValue());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static class BetterIterator {

        private final Iterator<Integer> iterator;

        private boolean hasNext;
        private Integer value;

        public BetterIterator(Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
            move();
        }

        public boolean hasValue() {
            return hasNext;
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void move() {
            hasNext = iterator.hasNext();
            if (hasNext) {
                value = iterator.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> a = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(5);

        List<Integer> b = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
        b.add(3);
        b.add(5);
        b.add(6);

        System.out.println(mergeListEfficient(a, b));
        //prints correctly [2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

**PS:** In case you allowed to modify your input you can simplify this code.

You can get rid of `BetterIterator`:

- `BetterIterator.hasValue` become `!a.isEmpty()`
- `BetterIterator.getValue` become `a.get(0)`
- `BetterIterator.move` become `a.remove(0)`